# Recently I had two upvotes but none of them getting added in my points

Tags: bug

Just now one incident happened with, I was answering question on SO. So my two answer got upvoted but none of them are showing points in Reputation tab. Only it showing upvote there[image]

You can see 2nd & 3rd is only showing upvote, points are not shown there

And the wiered thing is reputation bar on top of the bar is not showing those reputation entry, I don't know how & why this wiered thing is happening with me.

[image]

Can I know, why points are not getting added in my account, is it bug or I did something wrong?

Comment: You likely hit the [reputation cap.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it)

Comment: @Pekka웃 but then why next one gets added point correctly

Comment: Accepts and bounties are not capped.

Comment: @ArtjomB. that means further upvotes point will not get added into my account..Now I really go to bed now..Its nothing of my business now.will those point gets added later on..or never?

Comment: Yes, further upvotes will not get added until midnight UTC (= in 52 minutes). Any votes that occur after that will count again.

Comment: Re your update: the points that didn't count today will be lost.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for support..:) what is daily limitation then? is 350 or 200

Comment: 200 for normal votes. No limit for accepts and bounties, as Artjom said above.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Has something changed in the system? Because I thought at least 5 more upvotes shouldn't be counted in this case.

Comment: @Pekka웃 But how I get upvote points properly till 350 points..how? I think the limit is 350 yesterday I got 340 without any interuption like I got today..

Comment: @ArtjomB., pankajparkar - you gained only 200 points through normal votes. The rest is from accepts.

Comment: @Pekka웃 no you can visit my profile and see I got points from upvote and accepts to http://stackoverflow.com/users/2435473/pankajparkar?tab=reputation

Comment: Count the lines where it says "+10 upvote". There are exactly 20.

Comment: oh..that means i can have only 20 upvotes..that make sense..i understood now.i thought you were talking about total 200 points

Answer (score 3):

You can only get up to 200 reputation points daily from upvotes.

This is [clearly explained in the help centre page entitled "What is reputation?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit.
>
> You gain reputation when:
>   *[etc.]*

Please *read the documentation* when you have a doubt.